# How to create a c# windows form that keeps in the foreground of the application

Tags: c#, winforms, foreground

In my C# 2.0 application, I want to have a find/replace windows form which keeps in the foreground of the application, even when I click on the main form. You will maybe know these sorts of forms from Notepad++ and that's exactly how I also want my forms here.

I tried the obvious "TopMost = true", but then the form is in front of all the windows on my computer and not only in front of my application window.

Is there any way I can make such forms?

Comment: Winforms, Web Forms, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the parent (main) form to the `Show` method.

Comment: Wow, I never thought that this could be that easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `Show()` on the child form, you could call `ShowDialog()`

Of course this will be modal and persist to stay in front of the parent form. I.e. you must handle this new popup before you can interact with the parent form again.